# Reflected output voltage (VOR) in a transformer

Tags: voltage, transformer, flyback

What, exactly, does VOR mean, and how does it affect the number of turns, output voltage and controlling circuit in a flyback transformer?

Comment: have you googled 'flyback reflected voltage' ?  If not, do it. When you have, post some of your hits, and where you are stuck.

Comment: Over-simplified: output voltage times transformer ratio adds on top of your supply voltage when the switch is off. The transformer simply does transformer things, “copying” voltage from one side to the other at all times.